# Cisco Router GigabitEthernet interface can not add ip address?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

Cisco Router GigabitEthernet interface can not add ip address?

```
Router(config)#interface gigabitEthernet 2/1
Router(config-if)#ip add ?
% Unrecognized command
Router(config-if)#ip add 12.12.12.1 255.255.255.0
                  ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

who can tell me where is the issue?

my device is `CGR1240`.

Comment: There can be a few possibilities. Typically on a router, only the routed port (WAN) can have an IP address. Sometimes the port is by default a switchport, so that it needs `no switchport` before you can actually add an IP address. You could try to post the full configuration and `show version`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Cisco documentation:

> **Port Configuration**
>
> The Cisco CGR 1120 has 8 Ethernet ports: 6 FE
>   ports, and 2 GE switch ports. The Cisco CGR 1240 has 6 Ethernet ports:
>   4 FE ports and 2 GE switch ports. On both of the CGRs, you can
>   configure the 2 GE ports to operate in Layer 2 mode or the default
>   Layer 3 mode. You can convert the switch to Layer 2 mode by using the
>   switchport command.
>
> **Note:** Layer 2 switching is hardware switched. Layer 3 switching is
>   software forwarding.
>
> - > The FE ports are 100BaseT Layer 2. Traffic between different VLANs on
>   >     a switch is routed through the router platform using the switched
>   >     virtual interface (SVI). You can configure FE switch ports as Layer 3
>   >     (routed) ports by configuring the no switchport command on interface
>   >     fastethernet x/y . By default, FE switch ports are Layer 2.
> - > The GE
>   >     ports are 1000BaseT Layer 2. Traffic between different VLANs on a
>   >     switch is routed through the router platform using the switched
>   >     virtual interface (SVI). You can configure GE switch ports as Layer 2
>   >     ports by configuring the switchport command on interface gigabit
>   >     ethernet x/y . By default, GE ports are Layer 3 (routed ports). Any
>   >     switch port can be configured as a trunking port to connect to other
>   >     Cisco Ethernet switches.

Source: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/connectedgrid/cgr1000/ios/software/15_4_1_cg/FEvlan_switchconf.html

Answer (score 0):

The CG-Mech product you should pay attention, from the [document](https://manualsbrain.com/en/manuals/1650442/?page=66):

all the port, no matter FastEthernet or GigabitEthernet if you want to configure ip address, you should set `no switchport` firstly.